# C#　外部プログラムを起動させた際に、特定のフォームよりも前面に表示する方法

Tags: c#, windows

お世話になります。

C#にて、外部プログラム(calcやnotepadなど、exeで単体起動するもの)を呼び出すとき
(現在はProcess.Startを使用していますが、他の方法でも可)、特定のフォームより
必ず前面になるように表示されるようにする方法はありますでしょうか。

自分で作ったフォームなら、子フォーム.Ownerや、親フォーム.AddOwnedFormで実現できますが、
これを外部アプリに適用する方法です。

何卒よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Win32APIの[SetWindowLongPtr](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/SetWindowLongPtr.html)を使用します。

```
// 実際の処理
private void Form_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var p = Process.Start("notepad");

    SetWindowLongPtr(new HandleRef(p, p.MainWindowHandle), GWL_HWNDPARENT, Handle); // ※HandleはFormのプロパティ
}

// P/Invokeの定義 (pinvoke.net参照)
public static IntPtr SetWindowLongPtr(HandleRef hWnd, int nIndex, IntPtr dwNewLong)
{
    if (IntPtr.Size == 8)
        return SetWindowLongPtr64(hWnd, nIndex, dwNewLong);
    else
        return new IntPtr(SetWindowLong32(hWnd, nIndex, dwNewLong.ToInt32()));
}

[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SetWindowLong")]
private static extern int SetWindowLong32(HandleRef hWnd, int nIndex, int dwNewLong);

[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SetWindowLongPtr")]
private static extern IntPtr SetWindowLongPtr64(HandleRef hWnd, int nIndex, IntPtr dwNewLong);

private const int GWL_HWNDPARENT = -8;
```

なお相手ウィンドウのハンドルはこの方法では取れない場合がありますのでSpy++等で確認してください。

### 追記 (失敗した場合の対処)

ご指摘の通り上記の処理は他プロセスも絡むため必ず成功するわけではありません。
なので処理結果の判定とリトライが必要です。

一般論として検証方法は「引数の事前チェック」と「戻り値の判定」ですが、今回の場合成功した場合に返される「変更前の値」が`0`でエラー時の戻り値と区別できないため、別のAPIで設定値が反映されているか確認するのが良いでしょう。

// 設定値取得用の[`SetWindowLongPtr`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/cc411204.aspx)の定義

```
private static IntPtr GetWindowLongPtr(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex)
{
    if (IntPtr.Size == 8)
        return GetWindowLongPtr64(hWnd, nIndex);
    else
        return new IntPtr(GetWindowLong32(hWnd.ToInt32(), nIndex));
}

[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "GetWindowLong")]
private static extern int GetWindowLong32(int hWnd, int nIndex);

[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "GetWindowLongPtr")]
private static extern IntPtr GetWindowLongPtr64(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex);
```

// 起動およびオーナー設定

```
var p = Process.Start("notepad");

for (; ; )
    // TODO:無限ループにならないよう適当に上限を決める
{
    if (p.MainWindowHandle != IntPtr.Zero)
        // ハンドルが得られていない場合はSetWindowLongPtrを実行せず待機
    {
        SetWindowLongPtr(new HandleRef(p, p.MainWindowHandle), GWL_HWNDPARENT, Handle);

        // GWL_HWNDPARENTを再取得してNULLでないことを確認
        var owner = GetWindowLongPtr(p.MainWindowHandle, GWL_HWNDPARENT);
        if (owner != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    Thread.Sleep(1);
}
```

Comment: 回答、ありがとうございます。

教えていただいたのですが、初心者なもので、
Win32.apiの使い方がよく解っていません。

サンプルなどを掲示していただけますと幸いです。

お願いできますでしょうか。

Comment: @たたぱた とりあえず要点だけ書きます。まずリンク先のC# Signatureにあるメソッドを3個コピーします。次にDllImportがエラーとなると思いますので、using System.Runtime.InteropServices;を追加します。最後に定数GWL_HWNDPARENTの値は確か-8です。これで上記コードのコンパイルは出来ると思いますが、実行に失敗する場合はProcess.Startの後にSystem.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);などを入れてみてください。

Comment: pgrhoさん、ありがとうございました。

試してみた結果、希望通りの処理ができました。本当にありがとうございます。

ひとつ気になったのですが、これだけ大掛かりなメソッドを追加しないと、この機能は
実現できないのでしょうか。もっと簡単にできればありがたいのですが…。

今後ともよろしくお願いいたします。
ありがとうございました。

Comment: @たたぱた P/Invokeに慣れていないと呪文のように見えるかもしれませんが、実際の処理としては単に`SetWindowLongPtr64`を呼んでいるだけのシンプルなものですので…。

Comment: せっかく教えていただいて、上手くいっていたと思ったのですが、
必ず成功するわけではなく、同じexeファイルを起動させても、成功するときと
失敗するときがあります。Sleepの数値を上げたり下げたりもしていますが、
それでも失敗するときがあります。
確実にうまくいく方法は何かありますでしょうか。

Comment: @たたぱた 端的に言うと成功するまで実行すればよいです。通常の方法では成否が判定できないのでサンプルを追加しました。

Comment: 確実に成功させる方法は、相手側プロセスの都合もあるのでありません。
SetWindowLongPtr→(相手先で処理)→GetWindowLongPtrで状態取得という流れになりますが、この間で遅延する可能性もあります。

SetWindowLongPtr→p.WaitForInputIdle( 1000 )→GetWindowLongPtr→Sleep(200) のように WaitForInputIdleを挟むことで相手先プロセスがアイドル状態(暇になるまで)待機します。
無期限で待機することもできますが、相手先がフリーズしている場合も考慮し、タイムアウトを設定しておくべきです。

Comment: pgrhoさん、PITAさん、ご返答ありがとうございました。
試してみた結果、何とか成功するようになりました。
ただ、ExcelやWordなどのソフトはどうしても失敗してしまいましたが、
これらのソフトは検討していることではなかったので、
完全に成功した感じです。

本当にありがとうございました。

今後も、何かありましたらよろしくお願いいたします。