# C# Process.Startで起動する外部プログラムを、特定のフォームの中に表示させるには？

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

お世話になります。

以前、と規定のフォームの前面にProcess.Startで起動したプログラムが立ち上がるように
したいという質問をしたのですが([C#　外部プログラムを起動させた際に、特定のフォームよりも前面に表示する方法](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/9338/c-%E5%A4%96%E9%83%A8%E3%83%97%E3%83%AD%E3%82%B0%E3%83%A9%E3%83%A0%E3%82%92%E8%B5%B7%E5%8B%95%E3%81%95%E3%81%9B%E3%81%9F%E9%9A%9B%E3%81%AB-%E7%89%B9%E5%AE%9A%E3%81%AE%E3%83%95%E3%82%A9%E3%83%BC%E3%83%A0%E3%82%88%E3%82%8A%E3%82%82%E5%89%8D%E9%9D%A2%E3%81%AB%E8%A1%A8%E7%A4%BA%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E6%96%B9%E6%B3%95))、その方法について、少し問題があったので、今回、
メインのフォームの中に、MDIのように外部プログラムを起動させられればと思い、
新たに質問しました。

前回教えていただいた方法で、指定のフォームの前面にGoogleChromeを立ち上げたときですが、
常に前面にするように指定したはずが、メインのフォームをアクティブにすると、背面に隠れて
しまいました。

原因を調べてみると、このメインのフォームを起動する前に、通常の方法でChromeを一つ
立ち上げた後、今回のプログラムを開き、二つ目のChromeをProcess.Startで
立ち上げたところ、常に前面に表示されるという設定が効いていませんでした。
ほかにChromeが開いていないときならば、
このフォームから立ち上げたChromeは前面に来るのですが、どうやら多重起動するプログラムは
既に立ち上がっている場合は設定の変更ができないようです。

また、WordやExcelなどはそもそもこの設定ができずに、呼び出したメインウインドウが
アクティブになると、その背面に隠れてしまいます。

前置きが長くなりましたが、こういったことがあったため、MDIなどにすれば、間違いなく
メインフォームの中に表示されるだろうと考えました。

フォームの中にフォームを表示するのは、フォームのTopLevelをfalseにすれば簡単に
できますが、同じような結果になるようにProcess.Startで起動するプログラムを
メインフォームの子供フォームのように入れることはできますでしょうか。

ご教授お願いいたします。

[image: こんな例外が出ています]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`SetParent`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/cc411061.aspx)関数を使用するとウィンドウの親ウィンドウを変更することができます。

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern IntPtr SetParent(IntPtr hWndChild, IntPtr hWndNewParent);

[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern bool SetWindowPos(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hWndInsertAfter, int X, int Y, int cx, int cy, int  uFlags);

const int ASYNCWINDOWPOS = 0x4000;

var f = new Form();
f.IsMdiContainer = true;
f.Shown += (_, __) =>
{
    var p = Process.Start("notepad");
    p.WaitForInputIdle();

    // 親ウィンドウを設定
    SetParent(p.MainWindowHandle, f.Handle);

    // ウィンドウを移動
    SetWindowPos(p.MainWindowHandle, IntPtr.Zero, 0, 0, 100, 100, ASYNCWINDOWPOS);
};
f.Show();
```

ただしMSDNにも明記されている通り、他プロセスのウィンドウと親子関係を設定するのは保証外の動作になります。

Comment: いつも回答ありがとうございます。試してみたのですが、うまくいきません。画像を上にアップしますが、いただいたサンプルの「notepad」ならば動くのですが、その他の外部プログラムにこの例外が出ます。また、電卓『Calc』で試してみると、親子関係が有効にならず、通常起動されてしまいます。ちなみに、例外ではファイルが見つからないと出ていますがファイルはきちんと存在しています。

Comment: 画像の例外については`Process.Start`に失敗しているだけです。また「電卓」の実体はUWPアプリのため、calc.exeはウィンドウを持たずにApplicationFrameHostを起動して終了します。ですので`EnumDesktopWindows`などで`ApplicationFrameHost.exe`の「電卓」ウィンドウを探す必要があります。

Comment: すみません、やっぱりうまくいきません。PCを再起動して、上記の例外は出なくなったものの、きちんと外部プログラムが起動され‌​ても、親フォームの中には含まれません。通‌​常にProcess.Startで呼び出し‌​たのと同じように、通常に立ち上がってしま‌​います。WORDやEXCELも同じでした‌​。ちなみに、今回はUWPは考慮外ですので、それらについての対応は考えていません。

Comment: Excel 2010で試してみましたが、MDI化自体には成功していますがスプラッシュウィンドウがMDI子ウィンドウになっていますね…。ですのでこちらも`MainWindowHandle`ではなく表示したいウィンドウを自分で捜索する必要があります。他のプロセスについても単に間違ったウィンドウハンドルを指定しているだけだと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます。ほかのアプリで確かめてみた結果、仰るようにスプラッシュウインドウなどが前面に指定されているだけでした。それ以外はきちんと子フォームになっていました。ただ、質問に対する回答は間違いない方法でしたが、このようにできたりできなかったりではやりたいことがかなえられるわけではない感じですね。フォーム個別の指定ではなく、指定したexeファイル全てを子フォームにする方法はないでしょうか？

Comment: 前述の`EnumDesktop‌​Windows`でトップレベルウィンドウを列挙することはできるので、`GetWindowThreadProcessId`と併せて定期的に実行すれば各プロセスに属するウィンドウを取得することはできます。ただデスクトップには非表示のウィンドウも多く存在していますし、クラスやウィンドウスタイルなどでフィルタリングする必要があるため対象を特定せずに汎用的な処理が可能かは疑わしいです。